# How to calculate a 4-week period of the billing year

Tags: ruby

I'm refactoring a method that should return 4-week periods. A period is calculated as the number of 4-weekly blocks in the current billing year. There are thirteen periods per billing year. First billing year began on 24/08/2008.

I have created a formula:

```rb
def period
  period = (((self.utc.to_time - Time.new(2008,8,23,0,0,0,0)) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7 / 52).modulo(1) * 13).ceil
  period == 0 ? 13 : period
end
```

Over the years, it has become inaccurate, and we're now seeing a shift of a whole period: bookings in Period 1 are showing as Period 2. I tried re-calculating the formula with no success. I feel the formula is too complex anyway, and can probably be achieved more simply.

Comment: Define 4-week period. What day of week does a week start on? How are the first and the last week of a (billing) year defined?

Comment: This would be a good example to provide some assertions/specs for, along with the additional rules (What about leap years? And the extra day at the end of the year?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `Date` instead of `Time` and the calculation would be much easier.

```
DAYS_PER_PERIOD = 28

def period
  days = Date.today - Date.new(2008, 8, 23)
  periods = days / DAYS_PER_PERIOD
  periods.to_i # would return a `Rational` instead of an `Integer` otherwise
end
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. 

What the client threw in was that at some point in the last 11 years they changed the way they calculated periods and added an extra week somewhere. 

With a change to the start date (2008, 8, 23) to one after the extra week was thrown in, and the code above, we're good!